# Sorting an array while iterating by two?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm optimizing an algorithm that generates a texture for my game.. long story

Anyway, while profiling I found I could shave off an extra 10% off the runtime if I could eliminate converting vertex data from one format to another. Essentially, all vertex data comes in a single array like so: `[x0, y0, x1, y1, ... xn, yn]`

I need to sort the vertices first by X and then by Y. So far I've achieved this by converting the vertex data into an array of arrays like so: `[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], ... [xn, yn]]`

And then using `Array.sort((a, b) => a[0] > b[0] ? -1 : a[0] < b[0] ? 1 : 0)` and switching the index to sort by Y later and then convert back into the original format.

All this converting takes unnecessary time. Is it possible to somehow make `Array.sort()` iterate by two instead or some equivalent?

Other than that, I've also thought about implementing my own sort function. What are my odds of competing with the native `Array.sort()` performance wise?

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. Array.sort() always goes element by element, and there's no way for your comparison function to know whether it's comparing an even or odd index.

Comment: If you have an array of arrays, why would you want to iterate by two?

Comment: @HereticMonkey He doesn't have an array of arrays. He has to convert the flat array to that format, sort it, then convert back because the rest of the code expects it to be flat.

Comment: Which just raises the question: why does the rest of the code use this flat format instead of grouping the coordinates?

Comment: @Barmar because I've built it on babylon.js and that's the format it uses for vertices

Comment: Your comparison function can be simply `(a, b) => b[0] - a[0]`

Comment: **What are my odds of competing with the native Array.sort() performance wise?** It's probably implemented in optimized C or C++ code, so I wouldn't give you high odds.

Comment: Note that converting the pairs back to a flat list can be done with the built-in `Array.flat()` method, which should be faster than writing your own loop.

Comment: In case it matters, although your new vertex format probably shaves plenty of time off the runtime, have you checked whether the speed of the sort is significant? The time difference is probably not perceptable. When optimising the speed of game code, you should focus on things which affect the performance of the game first. Theoretical savings can be ignored.

Comment: @Barmar: subtracting doesn't work for edge values (+/- Infinity)
What is the expected output? If you sort first by indexes 0,2,4 and then separately by 1,3,5, maintaining the order of the first sort for equal elements is not guaranteed. Are pair connected? Do you want to compare 0 with 2 and then if equal 1 to 3?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a sorting of the indices and build a new array based in the indices.

```js
var data = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2],
    indices = [],
    result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) indices.push(i);

indices.sort((a, b) => data[a] - data[b]);

for (let i of indices) result.push(data[i], data[i + 1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Of course, we'd need to benchmark to see if this is actually faster than the OP's code.

Comment: Its a cool idea, I tried it but its slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun though because I don't believe this is gonna be faster that your existing solution - you can use proxy and iterators to make Array-like object which returns every second member:

```js
var input = [500,400,300,200,100];

var proxy = new Proxy(input, {
    get(target, name) {
        if (name === 'length') {
            return Math.ceil(target.length / 2);
        }
        if (name === Symbol.iterator) {
            return function*() {
                for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i += 2)
                    yield target[i];
            }
        }
        if (Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            return target[name];
        }
        return target[name * 2];
    },
    set(target, name, value) {
        target[name * 2] = value;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log([...proxy]); // [500, 300, 100]

proxy.sort((x, y) => x - y);

console.log(input); // [100, 400, 300, 200, 500]
console.log([...proxy]); // [100, 300, 500]
```